# Definition of imperative semantic in a HDL context

Tags: programming-languages, imperative-programming

I've been studying from [this book](http://unina.stidue.net/Architettura%20dei%20Sistemi%20di%20Elaborazione/Materiale/G.%20De%20Micheli%20-%20Synthesis%20And%20Optimization%20Of%20Digital%20Circuits%20(Text%20Recognized%20Using%20OCR)%20%5Bv.%201.03%2020-4-2005%5D.pdf) the topic of "Synthesis and optimization of digital circuit". In chapter 3 some theory about programming languages is exposed. I was wondering what's the meaning of this paragraph about the meaning of "imperative semantic"

> Languages with an imperative semantics are those where there is an
>   underlying dependence between the assignments and the values that
>   variables can take.

By surfing the web I've seen that basically these languages are "C/C++" like languages because how the program change its own state during his execution is specified by a sequence of statements in an explicit manner. However the topic of that book is basically how a circuit described using an HDL language is synthesized, and there's no "actual program there", and I can't relate how the "imperative semantic" concept provided is applied in such context. Is there a more rigorous definition of imperative semantic that applies to both context?